# How to paginate the get_users function?

Tags: function, pagination

Im using the get_users function to show a custom list of users on the site. The only issue Im having a problem figuring out now is how to paginate the result.

This is a sample of the function that Im using:

```
<ul>
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'jabber',
        'meta_value' => 'User Name',
        'meta_compare' => 'LIKE',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'count_total' => true,
        'fields' => 'all',
      );


    $blogusers = get_users($args_1);
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {

        $user_id = $user->ID; 
        $user = get_userdata($user_id);

          echo '<li class="provider-list prov-list-gradient">' . $user->display_name . '</li>';

    }
    ?>

    </ul>
```

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of creating a pagination for the this function. I would appreciate some help with this.

**UPDATE:**

This is the get_users function source code:

```
function get_users( $args = array() ) {

            $args = wp_parse_args( $args );
            $args['count_total'] = false;

            $user_search = new WP_User_Query($args);

            return (array) $user_search->get_results();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're running `get_users()` before you load each page of `N` results, you could revise your `get_users()` query to use the `OFFSET` keyword in mysql.

Pseudoquery example (where `P` is your page number):

```
SELECT * FROM USERS LIMIT N OFFSET N*P
```

Comment: Thank you Mirthquakes. Ive added the offset parameter to my query. Setting is to 8. From what I understand offset skips a number of users in the results. Im going to load the get_users function into a php file and have the foreach results listed using a template page. Im going to set N to 8, so that there will be 8 results per page. How can I use your mysql example to implement your solution?

Comment: A lot of it is up to you, but I was thinking maybe there would be another key/value pair in your $args array corresponding to the current page you're on (e.g. 'currentPage'=>'1'). Then, when your query is generated within get_users, you could append the offset expression. $query='... LIMIT '.N.' OFFSET '.N*currentPage

Comment: OK, there is a "number" parameter that "limits the total number of users returned." Maybe this is what I could use with your solution...But if this is correct I would need to set the *number* to be limitless, as I may have a large number of results. By including the *number* and *offset* parameter, I could probably use an example provided by you to get the pagination working...What do you think?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track. I guess I'm a little confused about the get_users() function. I might be able to give better advice if I could see that function's source code.

Comment: Hi Mirthquakes, I updated the post with get_users source code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were using Wordpress. It looks like you do not have control over the query that retrieves users. I took a look at this doc: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query. I can't seem to find a way to limit your results arbitrarily, so my approach may not work after all :(

Comment: I see... Well thanks for trying to help. I will see if there is another solution I can use. Thanks again!